# SQLite not allowing me to add entries for certain tables in database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

So basically the code works fine until i hit the line i commented  "//THIS DOESNT WORK!!!". then nothing is entered into the database.  Anyone know why i can enter them fine for the "StringCategory_Table" but not the other ones?

```
public class SetupOfSQLite{


    private DBHelper myHelper;
    private final Context myContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;

     private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "restaurantDatabase";
     private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
     private static final String COLUMN_RESTAURANT = "RestaurantName";
     private static final String COLUMN_CATEGORIES= "CategoryName";

     public static String currentRestaurant = null;
     public static String deletingRestaurant= null;

     public static final String American_Table ="Restaurant_List_American";
     public static final String Asian_Table = "Restaurant_List_Asian";
     public static final String BarPub_Table = "Restaurant_List_BarPub";
     public static final String Breakfast_Table ="Restaurant_List_Breakfast";
     public static final String FastFood_Table ="Restaurant_List_FastFood";
     public static final String Healthy_Table = "Restaurant_List_Healthy";
     public static final String Mexican_Table ="Restaurant_List_Mexican";
     public static final String SeaFood_Table = "Restaurant_List_SeaFood";
     public static final String Italian_Table = "Restaurant_List_Italian";
     public static final String Deserts_Table = "Restaurant_List_Desert";
     public static final String StringCategory_Table = "Categories_of_Restaurants";

     static ContentValues contValues = new ContentValues();

private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DBHelper (Context ctx){
     super (ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
     }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + American_Table       + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_RESTAURANT + " TEXT NOT NULL);");  
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Asian_Table          + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_RESTAURANT + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + BarPub_Table         + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_RESTAURANT + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Breakfast_Table      + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_RESTAURANT + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Deserts_Table        + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_RESTAURANT + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + FastFood_Table       + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_RESTAURANT + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Healthy_Table        + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_RESTAURANT + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Italian_Table        + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_RESTAURANT + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Mexican_Table        + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_RESTAURANT + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + SeaFood_Table        + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_RESTAURANT + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    // The table below is for keeping the categories persistent
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + StringCategory_Table + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_CATEGORIES + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    // The table below is for suggestions

    // now I'll create some entries for default categories
    contValues.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIES, "American"); 
    db.insert(StringCategory_Table, COLUMN_CATEGORIES, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIES, "Asian");
    db.insert(StringCategory_Table, COLUMN_CATEGORIES, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIES, "Bar or Pub");
    db.insert(StringCategory_Table, COLUMN_CATEGORIES, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIES, "Breakfast");
    db.insert(StringCategory_Table, COLUMN_CATEGORIES, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIES, "Deserts");
    db.insert(StringCategory_Table, COLUMN_CATEGORIES, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIES, "FastFood");
    db.insert(StringCategory_Table, COLUMN_CATEGORIES, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIES, "Healthy"); // this represents "Healthy" category
    db.insert(StringCategory_Table, COLUMN_CATEGORIES, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIES, "Italian");
    db.insert(StringCategory_Table, COLUMN_CATEGORIES, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIES, "Mexican");
    db.insert(StringCategory_Table, COLUMN_CATEGORIES, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIES, "SeaFood");
    db.insert(StringCategory_Table, COLUMN_CATEGORIES, contValues);

// now ill add in some restaurants for the first time the user installs the app 
//THIS DOESNT WORK!!!

    contValues.put(COLUMN_RESTAURANT, "Olive Guarden"); 
    db.insert(Italian_Table, COLUMN_RESTAURANT, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_RESTAURANT, "Red Lobster"); 
    db.insert(SeaFood_Table, COLUMN_RESTAURANT, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_RESTAURANT, "Outback"); 
    db.insert(American_Table, COLUMN_RESTAURANT, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_RESTAURANT, "Dunkin' Donuts"); 
    db.insert(Breakfast_Table, COLUMN_RESTAURANT, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_RESTAURANT, "Taco Bell"); 
    db.insert(Mexican_Table, COLUMN_RESTAURANT, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_RESTAURANT, "Burger King"); 
    db.insert(FastFood_Table, COLUMN_RESTAURANT, contValues);  //1st entry for fast food

    contValues.put(COLUMN_RESTAURANT, "McDonald's"); 
    db.insert(FastFood_Table, COLUMN_RESTAURANT, contValues);  // 2 entries for fast food

    contValues.put(COLUMN_RESTAURANT, "Cold Stone"); 
    db.insert(Deserts_Table, COLUMN_RESTAURANT, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_RESTAURANT, "Panda"); 
    db.insert(Asian_Table, COLUMN_RESTAURANT, contValues);

    contValues.put(COLUMN_RESTAURANT, "Subway"); 
    db.insert(Healthy_Table, COLUMN_RESTAURANT, contValues);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your tables are created?

Comment: That i am sure of.  I just decided that i want users to have some entries when they first start the app.  before they have to add places in manually.

Comment: And the stack trace of the exception is? I doubt you get the error message "It doesn't work".

Comment: JB Nizet, I figured this was a simple problem so i didnt post a logcat. I realize that was not a good choice and will do so in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `contValues` variable has stale column information that is not meaningful for the restaurant tables.  Try the following:

```
contValues.clear();
contValues.put(COLUMN_RESTAURANT, "Olive Guarden");
```

Comment: `ContentValues` is a `HashMap` internally and the column name is the key. Reusing the same `ContentValue` works only when replacing a key. Inserting does not clear the `ContentValue`

Comment: Thank you Guido Simone, this was exactly what fixed it.  Zapl, that now makes sense, i had no idea it was a hasmap. How do i find this type of thing out in the future?